# is there a way to delete rows where index labels change across the row

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am developing input into a networkx nodal chart to view traffic between submitters. The dataframe has multiple columns. I created a new column `submit_datetime_node_out` that duplicates the column `submit_datetime_node_in` but is shifted up one row. In this way, I can get durations between in nodes and out nodes. 
The problem is that when the work-order-id changes, I need to get the last row before it changes to be `None` so that I can delete it. Else the  `submit_datetime_node_out` for the last work-order-id entry captures the `submit_datetime_node_in` for the new work-order-id and creates a very long edge and distorts the results. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on this matter.

my code is as follows: ([df4_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNyMS.jpg) example attached)

```py
import pandas as pd

df4_1 = df3_1[
    ['Work Order ID', 'Service Request ID', 'Work_Order_Type', 'Support_Group', 'Priority', 'Submit_DateTime_Node_IN',
     'Submitter_Node_IN']]
df4_1['Submit_DateTime_Node_OUT'] = df4_1['Submit_DateTime_Node_IN'].shift(-1)
df4_1['Submitter_Node_OUT'] = df4_1['Submitter_Node_IN'].shift(-1)

from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

WOD = df4_1['Work Order ID']
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
WOD_LE_TRNS = le.fit_transform(WOD)
df4_1['WOD_LE_TRNS'] = pd.Series(WOD_LE_TRNS)

SDNO = df4_1['Submit_DateTime_Node_OUT']
WOD_LE_TRANS = df4_1['WOD_LE_TRNS']

for i in WOD_LE_TRNS:
    for j in SDNO:
        if df4_1.loc[i + 1, 'WOD_LE_TRNS'] != df4_1.loc[i, 'WOD_LE_TRNS']:
            df4_1.loc[j, 'Submit_DateTime_Node_OUT'] = None
        else:
            df4_1.loc[j, 'Submit_DateTime_Node_OUT']
```

Comment: Could you include some data directly in your question? And for your example data the desired output?

Comment: In the example attached above (df4_1), I need cell H22 to read 'None' so that i can filter and delete those rows. This will remove all false edges on the NetworkX  node chart that links end of one Word Order ID to a new Work Order ID. Thank you in advance for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by tagging the change in work-order-ID and then deleting those rows. This then removed all false edges in the NetworkX Node chart.
My code is as follows:

```
WOID = DF4_1['Work_Order_ID']
DF4_1['WOID_Check'] = (WOID.ne(WOID.shift(-1)))
DF4_2=DF4_1[DF4_1['WOID_Check'] == False]
```